# What is the simplest way to accept recurring donations? (except paypal)

Tags: payments, paypal, payment-gateway, non-profit

I'd like to put up a donation system for a nonprofit(outside US, central europe, no paypal/google checkout benefits apply) without too much coding/integration and with a checkout process as simple as possible from the user's POV.

Paypal is not an option, since for recurring donations it requires registration and the paygate is only in major languages.

What is the simplest/most efficient method to do this?

Comment: Are you saying the region is central Europe or some other region?  I there a specific language or set of languages you need the software to support?  Adding this clarity to your question will help us answer it.

Comment: yes, the region is central europe, i need slovak and hungarian language support or the ability to translate/localize the checkout page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at something like [Spreedly](http://www.spreedly.com) or [Recurly](http://recurly.com/). It's pretty simple to set up and they both have different ways to handle new subscriptions (through API or through a web form).

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Worldpay](http://www.worldpay.com/) then you could pull repeated donations by charging the users credit cards whenever they've agreed to this.